# Create JSON from Python classes with inheritence

Tags: python, json, oop, inheritance, data-modeling

I'm attempting to recreate the following JSON using python classes with inheritence :

```
{"attribute1": "c1"
"attribute2": {"attribute3" : "test"}
}
```

So far I have this code:

```
class class1():
    def __init__(self, attribute1):
        self.attribute1 = attribute1

class class2(class1):
    def __init__(self, attribute2):
        class1.__init__(self, 'test')
        self.attribute2 = attribute2

c1 = class1('c1')
c2 = class2(c1)

print(json.dumps(c1.__dict__))
```

renders:

```
{"attribute1": "c1"}
```

If I try to convert the variable `c2` to JSON:

```
print(json.dumps(c2.__dict__))
```

I receive error:

```
TypeError: Object of type class1 is not JSON serializable
```

Shouldn't `class1` be serializable as I convert it previously using `print(json.dumps(c1.__dict__))`

Comment: class1 dict is serializable, but class1 itself is not. You can pass a function to dumps to override this. e.g. `json.dumps(c2, default=lambda c: c.__dict__)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Shouldn't class1 be serializable as I convert it previously using print(json.dumps(c1.**dict**))

That isn't how JSON works.  It expects to find a dictionary at each level.  When you run, `json.dumps(c2.__dict__)` you've helped it find the dictionary for *c2*' but you haven't told it how to find the dict for *c1*.  It won't remember your previous call to `json.dumps(c1.__dict__)`

> I'm attempting to recreate the following JSON using python classes with inheritance

This likely won't work out cleanly.  Nested JSON models [HAS-A relationships](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Has-a) while inheritance models [IS-A relationships](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Is-a).